# What are the 37 Java API packages possibly encumbered by the May 2014 Oracle v Google decision?

Tags: java, android, oracle, dalvik, java-5

What are the 37 Java API packages possibly encumbered by the May 2014 Oracle v Google decision?

<strike>What are the 3 packages that the Appellate Court decided were essential to the language?</strike>

How can I avoid using the encumbered APIs in my Java code?

If the community were going to create a competing open classpath what would it look like?

UPDATE: as of May 2016 Google's use of these APIs has been ruled fair-use. http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/05/google-wins-trial-against-oracle-as-jury-finds-android-is-fair-use/

Comment: Amended for more relevance.

Comment: Discussion on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/259zr7/37_java_api_packages_potentially_encumbered_by/)

Comment: While this does involve licensing terms, it is a specific programming question that can have a definite answer. I believe that it can work here, so I've reopened the question.

Comment: I've trimmed the reddit post down so that the answer's detailed content is only present here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is seriously dancing on the line of what is and is not appropriate for SO, IMHO, but it's an important issue, so I'll tackle it.

> What are the 37 Java API packages possibly encumbered by the May 2014 Oracle v Google decision?

According to [the appellate court decision](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/1157205-13-1021-opinion-5-7-2014-1.html), they are:

- java.awt.font
- java.beans
- java.io
- java.lang
- java.lang.annotation
- java.lang.ref
- java.lang.reflect
- java.net
- java.nio
- java.nio.channels
- java.nio.channels.spi
- java.nio.charset
- java.nio.charset.spi
- java.security
- java.security.acl
- java.security.cert
- java.security.interfaces
- java.security.spec
- java.sql
- java.text
- java.util
- java.util.jar
- java.util.logging
- java.util.prefs
- java.util.regex
- java.util.zip
- javax.crypto
- javax.crypto.interfaces
- javax.crypto.spec
- javax.net
- javax.net.ssl
- javax.security.auth
- javax.security.auth.callback
- javax.security.auth.login
- javax.security.auth.x500
- javax.security.cert
- javax.sql

Note that this is merely the roster that Oracle sued Google over, and does not necessarily represent all of the APIs to which Oracle claims copyright.

> What are the 3 packages that the Appellate Court decided were essential to the language?

<strike>I am not aware that they made any such statement. You are welcome to read through the decision to find what you are seeking.</strike>

The *court* did not decide anything was essential. *Oracle* claims that `java.lang`, `java.io`, and `java.util` are essential to basically do anything meaningful with the language.

> How can I avoid using the encumbered APIs in my Java code?

Don't write in Java. Anything written in the Java programming language will involve classes from the affected packages.

> If the community were going to create a competing open classpath what would it look like?

I am not aware that this would be technically possible.

For further legal analysis, please consult with qualified legal counsel.

Comment: I've found the 3 packages in the text of page 7. They are java.lang, 
java.io, and java.util. Does this change your answer?

Comment: @KarlthePagan: I have updated the answer to reflect what you found on that page.

Comment: Parts 3 and 4 of my question hinge on specific legal interpretation of this ruling and would descend into a discussion. I believe that makes your answer precise enough for this forum. Thanks.

Comment: May someone still write his own JDK with these package names?

Comment: @neoexpert: "For further legal analysis, please consult with qualified legal counsel".